# Access public static class' state from a separate class file

Tags: java, scope, visibility, class-visibility

I have a public static class within another public class as follows:

```
public class Foo<A> {
public static class Bar<A>{
    A firstBar;
    Bar(A setBar){
        this.firstBar=setBar;
    }
   }

public final Bar<A> instanceBar;

public Foo(A actualValue) {
    instanceBar = new Bar<A>(actualValue);
}

public Bar<A> getBar() {
    return instanceBar;
}
```

My objective is to access `instanceBar`'s state from a separate class file without a get method and without changing the visibility of `firstBar`. How do I accomplish this?

For example, the following says `not visible`.

```
public class RetrieveFirstBar {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             Foo z = new Foo(5l);
             Foo.Bar<Long> z2 = z.getBar();
             long k = z2.firstBar; //not visible!
        }
```

}

Comment: show us the code where you are trying to access `firstBar`.

Comment: It's not a visibility issue. `z2.firstBar` is an expression used in improper way. Try to print it out, or assign the value to some local variable. Will work fine.

Comment: @RohitJain Why does it keep saying it's a visibility issue? Also I went `long k = z2.firstBar` and it still says visibility.

Comment: are both the classes in the different package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean

```
class Foo<A>
```

Since you write "A firstBar;" you give package access to the variable:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

If you have the RetrieveFirstBar in the same package you will not have visibility problems. But, if you want to access it from everywhere you should write

```
public A firstBar;
```